# Paginate template name

Tags: pagination

I want to make pagination for posts. I am using `posts_nav_link()` in my `archive.php` to make links to previous/next posts and first ten posts are shown well.

However when I click on newer posts link, the url changes to `.../page/2`, but it leads me to `index.php`

I realize that I am missing a template file, but I don't know which one. I tried adding `paged.php`, but it still opens `index.php`

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Did you check template hierarchy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy ?